# how to execute two asynchronous functions with flutter?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, asynchronous, future

I have two functions in flutter. the first one is `belManager.writeCharacteristic` and the second one is `belManager.disonnect` I want to execute belManager.disonnect() after belManager.writeCharacteristic is completed. However for some reason bleManager.disonenct() is called before belManager.writeCharacteristic is completed.
this is the code:

```
   switch (currentState) {
                    case BluetoothDeviceState.connected:
          await bleManager!.writeCharacteristic();
                      await bleManager.disconnect()
                      break;
                    case BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected:
                      print("please connect");
                      break;
```

thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: What is `bleManager`?  If `disconnect()` is being called before `writeCharacteristic()` completes, then that means that the `Future` returned by `writeCharacteristic()` completes prematurely.  Whether that should be expected or not depends on the documented contract for that function.  Another possibility is that you aren't actually observing what you think; for example, perhaps you're observing `writeCharacteristic()` being called again after `disconnect()` has been called.  It's hard to help you further without more details about exactly what you're doing and exactly what you're observing.

Comment: it might also help to know how you are sure that `belManager.disonnect` is completing before `belManager.writeCharacteristic`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps and update your question with more detailed code if it doesn't help:

- Check if your function has `async`, without it all the awaits are useless.
- Put a `try/catch` inside the switch, so if it generates an exception, you can easily find it.
- Call the `disconnect()` method inside a `.then()` right after your `writeCharacteristic()`, by doing so you should be able to "force" firing `disconnect()` method only when `writeCharacteristic()` is completed.
- Check if the Future from `writeCharacheristic()` is normally completed and it does what it should.

If this doesn't help please comment below and update your question, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your logic inside Async Function so you can easily await the methods.

```
  getConnectionStatus(var currentState)async{
switch (currentState) {
  case BluetoothDeviceState.connected:
    await bleManager!.writeCharacteristic();
await bleManager.disconnect()
break;
case BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected:
print("please connect");
break;}}
```